# File does not exist? Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: - Java

Tags: java, filenotfoundexception

I'm working on a project for class and I'm attempting to create a method that will read a file and fill an array. Inside the method I'm also using another method called from a class I've created. I prompt the user to enter the file to be read and no matter what I seem to do I keep getting an error that the file does not exist.

Here is the beginning code I'm working with:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter the file to read from:");
    String readFile = input.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Enter the number of accounts in the file: ");
    int size = input.nextInt();
    Account[] Accounts = readFile(readFile, size);
    Account[] invalidAccounts = new Account[34];
    for (int i = 0; i < Accounts.length; i++) {
        String password = Accounts[i].getPassword();
        if (isValidPassword(password) == false) {
            invalidAccounts[i] = Accounts[i];
        }
    }
    createDistributionList(invalidAccounts);
}
public static Account[] readFile(String readFile, int size) throws Exception {
    Account[] Accounts = new Account[size];
    File myFile = new File(readFile);
    Scanner fileInput = new Scanner(myFile);
    for (int i = 0; i < Accounts.length; i++) {
            int stuID = fileInput.nextInt();
            String name = fileInput.next();
            String username = fileInput.next();
            String password = fileInput.next();
            Accounts[i] = new Account(stuID, name, username, password);
    }
    return Accounts;
}
```

Here's the trace I'm getting if I use quotes:

```
Enter the file to read from:"studentdata.txt"
Enter the number of accounts in the file: 34
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: "studentdata.txt" (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:146)
    at java.util.Scanner.<init>(Scanner.java:656)
    at accountdriver.AccountDriver.readFile(AccountDriver.java:38)
    at accountdriver.AccountDriver.main(AccountDriver.java:25)
Java Result: 1
```

And here's the trace without quotes:

```
Enter the file to read from:studentdata.txt
Enter the number of accounts in the file: 34
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:909)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1530)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2160)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2119)
    at accountdriver.AccountDriver.readFile(AccountDriver.java:40)
    at accountdriver.AccountDriver.main(AccountDriver.java:25)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 7 seconds)
```

And here is the properly working code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter the file to read from:");
    String readFile = input.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Enter the number of accounts in the file: ");
    int size = input.nextInt();
    Account[] Accounts = readFile(readFile, size);
    Account[] invalidAccounts = new Account[34];
    for (int i = 0; i < Accounts.length; i++) {
        String password = Accounts[i].getPassword();
        if (isValidPassword(password) == false) {
            invalidAccounts[i] = Accounts[i];
        }
    }
    createDistributionList(invalidAccounts);
}
public static Account[] readFile(String readFile, int size) throws Exception {
    Account[] Accounts = new Account[size];
    File myFile = new File(readFile);
    Scanner fileInput = new Scanner(myFile);
    for (int i = 0; i < Accounts.length; i++) {
            int stuID = fileInput.nextInt();
            String name = fileInput.nextLine();
            String username = fileInput.nextLine();
            String password = fileInput.nextLine();
            Accounts[i] = new Account(stuID, name, username, password);
    }
    return Accounts;
}
```

I just needed to add Line to the end of each fileInput.next when I was attempting to read in  strings.

Comment: Please post the stack trace to help us better diagnose the issue.  Also please provide us with what you are trying to pass as an input.

Comment: If it says the file does not exist, then the file probably does not exist. You should try to hardcode it: `File f = new File("harcoded file name here"); System.out.println(f.exists());` to narrow down the issue.

Comment: Are u sure, that a file exist in that location?

Comment: Try `File myFile = new File(readFile.trim());`

Comment: where is the file located, where is your executable being called from  and what are you entering in the input

Comment: try checking with http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#exists()

Comment: I added the trace results. And I'm positive the file exists. It's inside the folder of the project. I've tried using the full length path as well to no avail.

Comment: I apologize for the horrible formatting. I'm new to the website.

Comment: This is probably because of the format of the tokens and new lines in the data. when it gets to nextInt() in the second iteration of the loop the last .next() call didnt eat the right amount of line feeds, or the data is just plain misalligned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stacktrace contains

> "The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect"

suggesting there are special characters in the name. It looks like you are putting " quotation marks around the name.

```
Enter the file to read from:"studentdata.txt"
```

You would use quotation marks if the filename was a Java string in the source code, but when inputting text via the console, these are not required.

Comment: Alright that makes sense. But I get another error if I don't use quotes. I'll add that up in my questions.

Comment: not using the quotes worked (it opened the file). you then just got subsequent errors because it couldnt parse the file :)

Comment: So why is the file not being parsed?

Comment: InputMismatchException suggests that when it tries to read an int, an int is not there. either the file is just wrong, or its not handling new lines (or something like that), as you expect it to. i suggest putting some debugging in to print each symbol as it reads it (after each scanner.next() - and see where it breaks).

Comment: Wow how sad. Where I was attempting to read in the strings I didn't have .nextLine() I just had .next() which was causing the file to not be parsed... Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: no worries. if you feel this answer showed the cause of the problem you can mark the answer as correct :)

Answer (score 0):

`FileNotFoundException` will either mean your file (name) doesn't exist, or the file is in the wrong location.

If you're going to read the file path as `"studentdata.txt"`, what you need to understand is that, if working from an IDE, normally it tries to look for the file in the current working directory, which is the project root. So your file would need to be there.

You may instead just want to use the absolute path instead like `C:/path/to/file.txt`

In cases where the file will be an embedded resources, you may want to use `MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream(fileName)` where the file would be in the class path. So you could do

```
InputStream is = MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream(fileName);
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(is);
```

Where your file would be in the same package as your class, if you're just going to use the file name as the path.

So you have some things to consider.

Comment: I have the file in the project root. I've also tried using the absolute path to no success. I'll try and use InputStream to see what I can come up with. I'm newer to Java so I've never actually used the InputStream. It's telling me the class isn't static so it can't be used and then it says something about URLs.

Comment: @SlipperySeal I didn't even catch that +1

Answer (score 0):

You need to copy and paste the text file "studentdata.txt" into the project file(navigate to the specific project name)inside the location of NetbeansProjects. t should work just fine!